# difference between `sort -k1` and `sort -k1,1`

Tags: linux, sorting, command

I think the only difference should be something about the stability.

So I think, if the first key is different, `-k1` and `-k1,1` should be same.

But,

```
$ cat test
A\  1
A   4
A B 3

$ cat -A test
A\^I1$
A^I4$
A B^I3$

$ sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 test
A   4
A\  1
A B 3

$ sort -t$'\t' -k1 test  # tab is larger than backslash?
A\  1
A   4
A B 3

$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

Are there any rules when `sort` handles backslash?

---

I modified this question with a more simpler example.

Comment: `man sort` shows `-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]     start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS (default end of line)...`

Comment: @shellter I think `15zd970\    1`  > `15zd970 4` . But `sort` outputs differently.

Comment: update your Q with output from `sort --version` . Sorry, but I won't have time to dig thru the sort source code to determine if this is a bug. Good luck.

Comment: Good update. But eliminate confusion about are these space separated columns or tabs but using `|` as your column sep. I think sort is working correctly, as with `-k1,1` it is only guaranteed to sort by values in the first field, where as `-k1` essentially sorts by the complete value of the line. Else it is a bug (highly unlikely). Are  you using any of the `LANG` variables in your environment, that can effect sort order too. Ok, Got to goto bed, good luck.

Comment: Very helpful comment! the ‘|’ solves my quetion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat testbar
A\|1
A|4
A B|3

$ sort -t'|' -k1,1 testbar
A|4
A\|1
A B|3

$ sort -t'|' -k1 testbar
A\|1
A B|3
A|4
```

As you can see, 
`-k1` option make the `sort` compares strings by **their length** first.

If you want to make `sort` work intuitively, use `-d` option.

```
$ sort -t$'\t' -k1 -d testbar 
A B|3
A\|1
A|4
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe. I would look at the Ascii values of the backslash, space and pipe chars. Glad you're making progress. Good luck!